# How to get last number in a row on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC0GL.png)
So Basically i'm building a sheet to monitor my NW, my problem is simple, i need the 2023 column to adapt to whatever last number on that row there is, for income i just sum values, but for example the total amount in my bank account is different every month, i just need 2023 column to track that, i update the 31 of each month.
With the formula you can see in the screenshot i have some problem, if i input the number alright, if the value is defined by other formulas it won't show up. Any solutions?
THANKS

[Only formula present in the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOpA1.png)

[Another formula from the comments that seems to not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4sDw.png)

I tried =INDEX(X:Y;1;COUNTA(X:Y)) but it won't update if the last number in the row is generated by other formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't show what formula in columns Jan-Dec causes you problems. If formula produce values 0 in case you don't what them to count, you can use `countif` to filter them out:

```
=INDEX(D13:O13,1,COUNTIF(D13:O13,">0"))
```

Same as your solution, this only works if columns are filled sequentially - if there are no gaps in each row, e.g. Jan and Mar are filled while Feb is blank.
If you need a more general solution, you may go with series of nested `if(isblank()`. Here is an example for the first three months, to get an idea:

```
=INDEX(D13:O13,1,IF(ISBLANK(F13),if(ISBLANK(E13),1,2),3))
```

Comment: @LC98 It may be, but i cannot see why. The community here is trying to help. In order to help the community help you, it would be nice to provide more details. 
I re-created relevant parts of your sheet, entered `=INDEX(D13:O13,1,COUNTIF(D13:O13,">0"))` in P13 and it gives the last value entered in D13:O13, in case there is no gaps in values. Have you tried something else? What are problems you encountered exactly?

Comment: Not working.   The formula is simple, i have another tab where i track expenses, if i move money from one bank to another, or to a broker i have a column "To Myself", so for example D13 is "=4275 - Expenses!D30",  4275 is the total amount of liquidity in my main bank, Expenses!D30 is the total amount of money i moved to let's say Revolut, Revolut column is just = 0 + Expenses!D30. If i put "," after coordinates they just appear as regular text, i tried ; but still not working, thanks!

Comment: @LC98 This clarifies a few things. You may consider putting the explanation of the formula in the main question text - there is an Edit button there. 
Do you want to count values <0 also? For example if `Expenses!D30` is 5000, value in D13 will be -725. Is this possible?

Comment: @LC98 if the formula appears as text, check whether there is a blank before `=`, and remove it. It will be then interpreted as formula.

Comment: -725 is correct but i don't mind counting <0 values since it is very unlikely to happen. =INDEX(D13:O13,1,COUNTIF(D13:O13,">0")) gives me back an error in P13, is there a way to include some other screenshots there?. No blank before or after "="

Comment: Got it working with  =INDEX(D13:O13,1,COUNTIF(D13:O13,">0")), i just needed to change international settings to US

Comment: @LC98 Great! I'm glad you reach a satisfying solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to find the last value of each row in the range D2:O26. Adapt it as needed!

```
=BYROW(D2:O26,LAMBDA(e,XLOOKUP(1,INDEX(1/(e<>"")),e,,0,-1)))
```

Explanation:

- `BYROW` creates an array formula in each row of the range. To each row, here denoted as `e`, the specified [lambda function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) is applied.
- `INDEX(1/(e<>""))` returns an array with `1` in places where cell is not empty, and `#N/A` for empty cells.
- `XLOOKUP` finds the index of the last occurrence (parameter `search_mode` set to `-1`) of 1 (first parameter) in the array returned by `INDEX` and returns corresponding value in the row.

Comment: So the formula gives me back an error, also "," after D2:O26 don't work, tried with ";" and it enlighten the range, but still gives me error